# How to prevent Android Studio delete wildcard imports with the "Optimize imports on the fly" option

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How can I prevent Android Studio to delete the imports with a wildcard if with the **Editor > General > Auto Import > Optimize imports on the fly** option is enabled?

In example with this option all my tests get the junit.Assert import deleted before I can use it

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Comment: why you want to delete it? you start using api's you need imports will be managed by android studio automatically.

Comment: I dont want to delete it. I want to prevent the deletion when the Optimize imports on the fly is enabled

Comment: question is why you want to do that?

Comment: Because if it gets deleted, when I try to use a statement like, in example. assertTrue I need to re-import it, slowing me down

Comment: It will get imported automatically when its required. you need not to write it manually. also wildcard imports are not recommended.

Comment: You really should avoid wildcard imports, it is considered a bad practise in Java, because of possible conflicts in future and name collisions between different packages, especially when using 3rd party libraries.

Comment: From the Kotlin style guide: `Wildcard imports (of any type) are not allowed.` https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide

Answer (score 64):

Although wildcard imports are not recommended, you can use it if you modify the settings in the **Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports** Just set the *Class Count* value to 2 or 3.

[image: Imports]

Comment: Go to Editor->Code Stye->KOTLIN->Imports when using Kotlin!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this for Kotlin, there is a more detailed answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67341958/1689960

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Answer**

Android Studio > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin > Imports, then select these two options:

1. Top-Level Symbols - *Use single name import*
2. Java Statics and Enum Members - *Use single name import*

> *Note: If you are using **Java**, you can do same thing with selecting Java
> under Code Style in left menu.*

[image]