# How do I disable Wildcard imports for all Kotlin files in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The [Android Kotlin Style Guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#import_statements) says:

> Wildcard imports (of any type) are **not allowed**.

How do I configure Android Studio to do this automatically?

Answer (score 160):

You can set your Android Studio preferences to remove all wildcard imports from Kotlin files.

1. Open Android Studio Preferences: `Editor > Code Style > Kotlin`
2. Select `Use single name import` for *Top-level Symbols*
3. Select `Use single name import` for *Java Statics and Enum Members*
4. Remove all packages from *Packages to Use Import with* by clicking the minus `-` symbol until it says `Nothing to show`

For each Kotlin file, you can fix imports with `Code > Optimize Imports` (shortcut `⌃⌥O` on Mac).

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio 4.1.2 Settings: No Kotlin Wildcard Imports]

Comment: I am trying this on Windows and after making these changes, optimizing imports does not fix the wildcard. I tried to restart Android Studio, but nothing changes. Any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Same here, doesnt fix automatically

Comment: Applying this preference in the settings won't change the code automatically, but it will force all future imports to be avoid using wildcards. One solution to force the change on all imports is to manually delete all instances of wildcard imports and let the IDE recreate them again-

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 you can do the following to disable wild cards for Java:

Go to *File > Settings > Code Style > Java > Under General select "Use single class import"*

Next to **Class count to use import with '*':** AND **Names count to use static import with '*':** increase the number from *99* to high value for example *995*

[image]